# Set a qualification based on tags to 'vote to close'

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have been noticing an alarming trend of late - I've asked around 150 questions on SO over 7 years, but for the past year or so, 50% of my questions get votes to close. Quite often I notice that, based on their tags, people voting to close my question probably do not understand the question well enough or they have no idea about the specific domain/technology.

For example, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38708314/counting-number-of-steps-to-match-regex. This was primarily a Java question. Why do people with few  contributions to questions in [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) get to vote to close this question? Shouldn't there be a specific qualification (defined by high contribution to tags related to the question) for voting to close?

Comment: could you please care to explain the downvote? This is exactly what I am talking about. Like one of the mods said, this is no reddit. So, what exactly is it called when people jump to downvote with no explanation as if this is a 'hot or not' question? Do you see my point of how SO is changing? People downvote for the heck of it. It is so hard to have a meaningful discussion on meta, which is supposed to be the place for discussion??

Comment: That question was closed by some high level SO users for being **too broad**, If people don't understand your questions as you say - Try to improve it

Comment: I downvoted because this question has been asked several times.

Comment: *"...people playing nanny (just to increase their reputation points for their CVs)"* - you don't get rep from closing questions. Indeed closing it means you can't add an answer, which is the only way you *could* earn rep from it once you're over the cut-offs for gaining rep from accepted edits. By *"one of the mods"* do you actually mean an elected moderator or one of the voters to close?

Comment: This nanny was about to down vote but that ^ guy saved the post ...

Comment: `Do you see my point of how SO is changing? ` Questions have been downvoted on Meta for time immemorial, for much more loose reasons on the main site. Your example question is really, really broad and it's hard to imagine it would not have been closed at any point in time except maybe in the first two years the site existed. It does not take domain knowledge to see that.

Answer (score 11):

Your example question is three sentences long. The first states what a third party web site does. The second two are very broad questions, then it ends with a picture.

> How do find this number in Java with my patterns ?
>
> Is there anything in the Pattern class that gives this information?

---

Your question was closed as "too broad". The first question is asking about how to find it with "my patterns". The second is asking for a recommendation to either documentation or a third party library/module/snippet of code. Both of those are broad.

You haven't provided any code showing your problem. "But, it's right there in my screenshot!" you say. Huh. So it is...kind of. There is a regular expression, but no Java code.. Guess what I can't do with that screenshot...copy and paste your code so I can test with it. "Code" is not an image. "Code" is text. If you are asking for help regarding your code, you need to provide your code.

The goal here is to get help. We can't help you if you aren't providing us with examples of what you've tried and explain why they fail. We also *won't* help you search for libraries or documentation. That is your responsibility as a developer. When you find something and have tried it and that doesn't work, that is when Stack Overflow should get involved. We aren't Google. We work with practical problems that you are having.

---

In short, if your other questions are like this you need to:

- Provide code, not images
- Ask a question related to your code, not a general "how do I do this in Java?"
- Not ask for a link to documentation. A good answer will either provide that, or provide an extract anyway.
- Screenshots should be used to convey useful information, not for showing your code, example data, error messages or any other block of text that someone may need to type in to help you.

Comment: Are you suggesting that all of the millions of questions on SO with java tag have CODE specified? Do you want me provide you with thousands of questions with "popular question" which had nothing to do with code? Ok, may be I did not code this, yet - but, tell me something, do you always code everything that you see blindly? Do you not research and see if you are trying to reinvent the wheel? Do you not ask your fellow developers at work if they have seen something before?!

Comment: Please understand that not everything in this world is a coding problem - if it is, then I suggest that you remove tags from SO that are non-programming related, such as "design", "architecture", "performance", "testing", "scalability" - Why don't we only have, "JAVA", "C", C++ and bunch of other language names, coz this is PROGRAMMERS ONLY SITE and every question is only about CODE in your question.

Comment: The question I asked is to draw attention for opinions from people who know what I talking about - to either tell me that yes, this has been tried before, or it can't be done because the Pattern class won't allow it. It was supposed to provide direction, but by voting to close with in a matter of seconds, esp by people who are not familiar with the context of the question, you are not giving a chance for other people who could have answered it, a chance to even VIEW it.

Comment: @Jay you understand that closed questions can still be viewed, right? Users can't add an answer, but if they feel the closure was unfair they can vote/flag to reopen. *"not everything in the world is a coding problem"* - and not everything in the world belongs on SO. You can argue about the precise scope, but your question was clearly not appropriate.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I made the mistake of assuming that closed questions can't be viewed. My fault. I even opened a question on it on meta, and I realized from the answer provided to it that closed questions get same views. I accept my fault. The reason don't know much about closed questions is that I've not asked many questions in the past that were closed, so I was not familiar with what happens to closed questions. So, yes, it was my ignorance.

Comment: I disagree with the idea that the question needs code. It doesn't. It is very clear what the user wants: a function that, when given a regex and a string, will return the number of steps needed in the match. The problem with the question is not that it doesn't provide code. The problem is that it's basically asking someone to write a (very non-trivial) piece of code for him. Hence closing it as "too broad" is entirely valid. The idea that every question needs code is wrong.